# Two outdoor outlets not functioning..what is the most likely cause

Tags: receptacle, gfci, outdoor

I have two outdoor electrical outlets that are not working.
They are both GFCI and close to each other.
10 feet above one is a floodlight receptacle that is controlled by an interior switch inside the room  behind it.
[image]
There are two working  electrical outlets on the interior room wall that appear to be directly behind the dead  exterior outlets

I have tried reseting  the GFCI buttons on both of the dead outlets and have not found an inside GFCI receptacle the might be connected to.

Any guesses as to what may be causing these outside dead outlets or why they might have been installed close to each other

Comment: Question...did you just move into this home and notice this problem, or were these previously working but mysteriously quit? Just to rule out the obvious, did you check your breaker panel for tripped circuits? Also, it's possible those outdoor receptacles are controlled by switches somewhere indoors.

Comment: Are there any indicator LEDs on the GFCI receptacles?  Did you check to see if a breaker is tripped or switched off?

Comment: Have you checked all the gfci outlets in the house? Sometimes people go from one gfci to another.

Comment: the plugs appear to be arranged symmetrically with respect to the window, suggesting that they may be for christmas decorations ..... if that guess is correct, then there may be a wall switch that turns them off

Comment: Did you check the service panel--is power going to the GFCI?

Answer (score -2):

If the GFCI is old, change it. Open up and look inside for critters and dirt.. blow it out. I like the guy who thinks your outlets are for Christmas ornamentation!! Look for that wall switch. Why two GFI? That means two different circuits... right? Do you want to keep these outlets functioning? GFIC grounding method is sometimes in error.  Get a head lamp and start tracing the lines. Connect the outlet to a LOUD radio with out the GFCI and go flick the circuit breaker/fuses. For CB's, flick "All the way OFF" first, then flick them on. Spongy flick? Change the CB. Youtube testing CB's.

Comment: It's rather difficult to tell the instruction/suggestion from the commentary in your answers. Please feel free to use the `<Enter>` key to include some formatting - If it's easy to read, it's easy to follow for non technical folk.

Comment: Technical folk are not any fonder of "wall-of-text" than non-technical folk, really. Good readability makes for better, clearer, technical documentation